# Group Joins with multiple tables converting SQL to Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

Can anyone help me by translating this SQL Statement to Linq?

```
SELECT a.KPI, a.ProcessDate, a.Actual, lf.LPLocal, pf.LPProd, d.LocalDelta, d.ProdDelta
FROM
    Actual AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Local l ON l.Date = a.Date
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Prod  p ON p.Date = a.Date
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Delta d ON d.Date = a.Date
```

I have done some research and came up with this:

```
Dim Xq1 = (From a In tmpActual _
Group Join l In tmpLocal On l.Item("Dates") Equals a.Item("Dates") Into al = Group _
From x In al.DefaultIfEmpty() _
Group Join p In tmpProd On p.Item("Dates") Equals a.Item("Dates") Into ap = Group _
        From y In ap.DefaultIfEmpty() _
Group Join d In tmpDelta On d.Item("Dates") Equals a.Item("Dates") Into ad = Group _
From z In ad.DefaultIfEmpty() _
Select
    KPI = a.Item("KPI"), ProcessDate = a.Item("Dates"),
    AccountingActual = a.Item("AccountingActual"),
    LocalForecast = x.Item("LocalForecast"),
    ProdForecast = y.Item("ProdForecast"),
    Localdelta = z.Item("LocalDelta"),
    ProdDelta = z.Item("ProdDelta")).DefaultIfEmpty
```

But when I ran it it got:

> System.InvalidCastException was caught
>   Message="Unable to cast object of type
>   'd__9e`1[VB$AnonymousType_6`7[System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object]]'
>   to type 'System.Data.DataTable'."
>   Source="LPBenchmarking"   StackTrace:
>          at LPBenchmarking.BLL.GetKPIFromPrime(PreKPIData
>   ds, Int32 Outliers) in C:\Documents
>   and Settings\RSpalding.TCI\My
>   Documents\Libraries\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2008\Projects\LPB
>   Optimization\LPBenchmarking_Web\BusinessComponents\BLL.vb:line
>   204   InnerException:

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note that your original SQL is not using Group By, and you've got typos: lf. and pf. should just be l. and p. presumably.

Answer (score 0):

Try spliting the query into a number of sub queries and see which ones work (if any):

```
Dim alq = From a In tmpActual _
 Group Join l In tmpLocal On l.Item("Dates") Equals a.Item("Dates") Into al = Group

Dim apq = _
 From x In alq.DefaultIfEmpty() _
 Group Join p In tmpProd On p.Item("Dates") Equals a.Item("Dates") Into ap = Group

Dim adq = _
          From y In apq.DefaultIfEmpty() _
 Group Join d In tmpDelta On d.Item("Dates") Equals a.Item("Dates") Into ad = Group

Dim Xq = _
 From z In adq.DefaultIfEmpty() _
 Select
     KPI = a.Item("KPI"),
     ProcessDate = a.Item("Dates"),
     AccountingActual = a.Item("AccountingActual"),
     LocalForecast = x.Item("LocalForecast"),
     ProdForecast = y.Item("ProdForecast"),
     Localdelta = z.Item("LocalDelta"),
     ProdDelta = z.Item("ProdDelta")

Dim Xq1 = Xq.DefaultIfEmpty
```

*Note I've only edited the code you provided in SO -- I have not syntax checked it in an IDE!*